# Brownian motion and martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

The following theorem (picture below) is from Peres-Morters book: Brownian motion.

Consider an open $O \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and a $C^2$-function $f: \overline{O} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $(x,r) \in O \times \mathbb{R}_+,E_x[|f(B_r)|]<\infty$ and $E_x[\int_0^r |\Delta f(B_u)|]<\infty.$ Let $T:=\inf \{ r \in \mathbb{R}_+,B_r \notin O \}.$

We want to prove that for every $x \in O,f(B_{r \wedge T})-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{r \wedge T} \Delta f(B_u) du$ is a $P_x$-martingale.

**Is it possible to do that using the same argument of Theorem $2.51$ below?**

[image]

Comment: Isn't the process you are asking about just $X_{t \wedge T}$?  So can't you just use that a stopped martingale is a martingale?

Comment: the statement is true for $x \in O$ not for $x \in \mathbb{R}^d.$

Comment: Until now, your statement is not making use of the fact that $f$ is harmonic, btw.

Comment: You're right $f$ is harmonic could be omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be proved in the same way. As noted in the comments, when $f$ is harmonic the second term vanishes.

Comment: For $r \leq u,$ is it possible to compute $E_x[f(B_{T \wedge u})|\mathcal{F}_r]$ in term of $E_{B_{r \wedge T}}[f(B_{(u-r) \wedge T})]$?

Comment: Can we solve the problem by writing $$E_x[f(B_{T \wedge u})|\mathcal{F}_r]=\left(f(B_T)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T\Delta f(B_v)dv\right)1_{\{T \leq r\}}+1_{\{T>r\}}E_x[f(B_{T \wedge u})-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{T \wedge u}\Delta f(B_v)dv|\mathcal{F}_r]=\left(f(B_T)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T\Delta f(B_v)dv\right)1_{\{T \leq r\}}+1_{\{T>r\}}E_{B_r}[f(B_{T \wedge (u-r)})-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{T \wedge (u-r)}\Delta f(B_v)dv]$$ noting that if $T(\omega)>r$ then $B_r(\omega) \in O$ and $T(\omega)=r+T(\theta_r(\omega))$ and here the proof is similar to the above.